# Beamer to not output PDF automatically in presentation mode

Tags: beamer, emacs, auctex

I am using `beamer` with the [`wkbeamer`](http://www.few.vu.nl/~wkager/latex.htm) theme in Emacs and I can't figure out how to get it to not output in presentation mode, which is quite annoying when creating the document. Every time I view it the flag is set to automatically launch in presentation mode. Does anyone have experience in this matter or no where I can change the `beamer` settings for this? Or if this is possibly located in the [`wkbeamer`](http://www.few.vu.nl/~wkager/latex.htm) theme?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise.

Comment: With "presentation mode" you mean fullscreen in the PDF viewer? There is actually a `presentation` mode in `beamer` which the normal mode. There is a `handout` mode to produce handouts etc. The fullscreen mode setting is a `hyperref` setting. Have a look at its manual.

Comment: @MartinScharrer - Nope I meant as you answered below but still was wondering whether that overwrites the other previous set variables or just resets the one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is set in `beamerthemewkbeamer.sty` (the main `wkbeamer` theme file) using:

```
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode={FullScreen}, ...}
```

You should be able to change that setting after loading the theme with:

```
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode={UseNone}
```

If this doesn't work (some options are only valid the first time they are used), place that line before you load the theme.

Search the `hyperref` manual for `pdfpagemode` to get more details.

Comment: I had sorted that was the culprit and removed it from wkbeamer but that's even better. I'll put it back and it works just putting it below the loading of the theme. Will it overwrite the other settings like linkcolor, etc,... set for hyperref in the wkbeamer or just overwrites that one setting.

Comment: No, it will only overwrite the `pdfpagemode` setting.